# Why this error comes while using CryptoSwift framework in ios using swift language?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cryptoswift

For getting md5 hash tag in swift i am using the CryptoSwift framework. Followed the procedures of installing it and everything is done right. But while compiling i am getting errors in cryptoswift which is shown in image below. Swift really a headache in adding the framework . A half cooked language it is.

**/Users/###/Desktop/SwiftMD5String/CryptoSwift/Sources/CryptoSwift/BlockMode/CipherBlockMode.swift:15:47: Argument passed to call that takes no arguments**

This error occurs 17 times

and

it also shows import CryptoSwift -> **No module found for CryptoSwift**

Comment: @AshishKakkad It is a crazy language ...

Comment: Using git command as declared in the following link https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift

Comment: i used using git but no success

Comment: It is best to avoid using CryptoSwift, amoung other things it is 250 to 1000 times slower than Common Crypto based implementations. Apple's Common Crypto is FIPS certified and as such has been well vetted, using CryptoSwift is taking a chance on correctness and security. Times are for MD5 on an iPhone6s with data length of 1MB: 
Common Crypto 3.6 mSec 
CryptoSwift 787.1 mSec

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, and i solved it by forcing CocoaPods to install the version 0.2.1 of the library

```
pod 'CryptoSwift', '0.2.1'
```